# Stopping an Animation in render method LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have an animation of a flipping coin made of five Textures. I would like to `delete` the animation when the player's Rectangle overlaps the coin's Rectangle but since I haven't found how to do this, I want to just stop it.

With this code, I can draw a Texture above the Animation, but just if the player is overlapping. How can I make it definite? Thanks for the help.

```
public boolean catchcoin(Rectangle player, Rectangle coin){
   if (Intersector.overlaps(player, coin)) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

public boolean changecoin(Rectangle play, Coin coin ) {
   boolean b = m.pegamoeda(play, coin.getRectangle());
   if(b){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Part of the render method:

```
public void render(float delta){
   currentframe = (Texture) coin.returnsanimatio().getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
   currentframe2 =(Texture)coin2.returnsanimation().getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
   currentframe3 =(Texture)coin3.returnsanimation().getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
   sp.draw(currentframe, coin.getx(),coin.gety(), 30,30);
   sp.draw(currentframe2, coin2.getx(),coin2.gety(), 30,30);
   sp.draw(currentframe3,coin3.getx(),coin3.gety(), 30,30);
   boolean b = changecoin(player, coin);
   if(b){
      sp.draw(bluecoin, coin.getx(), coin.gety(), 30,30);
   }
   sp.end();
}
```

Comment: Of course, sorry for that.

Comment: Can you show the `Coin` class, please?